# Using window.location.origin in angular library configuration using AOT

Tags: javascript, angular, aot, angular-library

When I pass `window.location.origin` in the `forRoot({...})` configuration object argument of my angular library and compile using `AOT`, it's value is just null. Is there a way to pass it's value to my angular library with `AOT` enabled?

After some googling I'm thinking perhaps an injection token needs to be set with WINDOW and then consumed on the library side but I'd like to avoid this if possible. I can also just hard code the origin but that is quite limiting. Would like a sort of set it and forget it approach hence why I carved out a feature into a library.

My Library is set up as follows.

```
export class AppConfig {
  origin: string;
}

...

export const APP_CONFIG_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('APP_CONFIG_TOKEN');

...

@NgModule()
export class MyLibrary {
  public static forRoot(config: AppConfig) {
    return {
      ngModule: MyLibrary,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_CONFIG_TOKEN,
          useValue: config
        }   
      ]
    };
  }
```

I'm consuming the value of the token in a service within the library

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG_TOKEN) private config: AppConfig) { }

  myOrigin(): string {
    return this.config.origin; // expecting it to return a value like `http://localhost:4200` but it returns `null`
  }
}
```

and I'm importing the library in my `AppModule` like so

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyLibrary.forRoot({ 
      origin: window.location.origin // with AOT, this seems to be null
    }) 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I think it's all about passing a primitive. If you have passed a reference to an object you would get an actual value in it when the code is executed. So try replacing `window.location.origin` with `window.location`

Comment: Also, why would you want to pass a globally accessible data to you library whist you could access it right in your library's code?

Comment: @Sergey Well the library needs a URL value which for my purpose is the origin, this can be hard coded (for testing let's say) or the location origin. Just wanted to provide flexibility basically.

Answer (score -1):

AOT builds parts of the app so that the client has to do less computing.
Try looking at this issue

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10957